# Why do I have to refresh each page to get the jQuery to work properly on each of them?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, prepend

I'm using jQuery Mobile and I'm trying to move a simple list item around from one page to another.  Here's one snippet of code I'm using:

```
$('#YesNoMaybePage, #summaryPage').live('pageinit', function() {
$('.green, .blue, .red').click(function(){
    var $move = $('.purchase').prependTo("#summaryPage .theListItem");
});
});
```

Now this works great, when I refresh `#summaryPage`, click back to `#YesNoMaybePage` and execute the event.  It however does not work if i refresh the `#YesNoMaybePage` and than execute it.  I assume the html on the `#summaryPage` has not loaded when I refresh the `#YesNoMaybePage` and than that is the reason why it isn't working, but I honestly don't know.  Any ideas why that might be and how I can fix this?

Thanks a bunch world.  I love u.  For further clarification here's another snippet a code I have with the exact same issue:

```
$('#YesNoMaybePage, #categorizePage').live('pageinit', function() {
$('.green, .blue, .red').click(function(){
    var $move = $('.purchase').prependTo("#categorizePage .theListItem");
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are both these 'pages' in the dom at the same time? It appears that you are trying to prepend an html element to a page that isn't currently being displayed. That won't fly, you can only modify the currently loaded dom.

Comment: Yes, I think that's exactly the problem!  How can I put both pages in the dom at the same time?  I think that jQuery Mobile uses ajax and loads every page at once, and that's y i thought this would work, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What are you doing? Are you using a database? I have no idea what you're trying to do, but generally 'moving' an item from one list to another would happen by modifying the record in the database.

Comment: I'm not using a database... yet.  I'm building an App for the first time and trying to get as much accomplished before having a coder friend help me add the database.  I'm just trying to have a list item move from the first list to 1 of 3 other lists, depending on whether the user clicks red, green, or blue.  The other 3 lists are on 3 other pages.

Comment: Are the lists just stored in javascript? You can't just modify variables in one page, go to another page and have the changes persisted. Call your coder friend, or read about session variables.

Comment: Sweet.  I guess I've taken it as far as I can with just jQuery and CSS and to have the changes persist I need to add a backend?

Comment: Not sure if you've taken it as far as you can or not, but to do what you're asking your best bet is to hook into a database.

Comment: Cool  Dude.  Thanks for answering and not making me slave away at something impossible all night.  : )

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because your javascript is included in your summarypage.html and not in your yesnomaybepage.html.
This is an expected behaviour with jqm.
You have to either include the same js in every pages of your site, or pack all your page into a single html file.
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/multipage-template.html

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem before. My problem is with the turbolink. By disable it it work perfectly for me. Here is a very easy way to remove it:
Go to `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Just remove the equal sign in front of turbolink

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
// require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

And that's it