# Can I load all my jQuery Mobile pages at once using $.mobile.loadPage() ?

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-mobile, load

I want to load every page into the DOM at once.  Can I do that?  Do i use `$.mobile.loadPage()`?  In my script.js file do I write something like this:

```
$('#YesNoMaybePage, #categorizePage').load("#YesNoMaybePage, #categorizePage");
```

??? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still really want to load all your 'pages' at once, you'd put them all in one file, and  put each 'page' in it's own div. You'd then hide the div's for all the 'pages' except the one that you are currently showing.

As far as actually loading the pages, yes, you could do it as you suggest, as long as you change the second parameters to filenames and separate the loads as Jai suggests:

```
$('#YesNoMaybePage').load("YesNoMaybePage.html");
$('#categorizePage').load("categorizePage.html");
```

Comment: Thanks buddy.  I'll let it go :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes do it this way:

```
$('#YesNoMaybePage').load("YesNoMaybePage.html");
$('#categorizePage').load("categorizePage.html");
```

This way you can load pages simultaneously.

Comment: Sure, you could do that, except that you wouldn't load the contents from one element into that same element, or have filenames that look like "#YesNoMaybePage"

Comment: Yes thats the OPs version of code he would understant it. i think.

Comment: although i have put extension `.html` here.

Comment: Thanks Jai.  99miles was helping me from a previous question.  I wanted to move list items around from one page to another and he recommended that I include a database instead of attempting to do this  only using jQuery.

Comment: For the record, here's his previous post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331317/why-do-i-have-to-refresh-each-page-to-get-the-jquery-to-work-properly-on-each-of